# Adding each value in an RDD to its partition number

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Quite new to PySpark so this might be simple. I have an RDD that ranges from 1 to 100 and has 4 partitions.

```python
A = sc.parallelize(range(100), 4)
```

And I have to find a way to return another RDD where each value in the RDD is added to its partition number. The ideal example would be:

```python
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 
40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 
60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 78, 79, 
80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 
99, 100, 101, 102]
```

Would like to know how I could amend the following code to get the desired results.

```python
A = sc.parallelize(range(100), 4)

B = 

print(B.collect())
```

Comment: do you want to output the actual partition number or just the values that are in the partitions grouped by partitions? the latter can be achieved by `rdd.glom().collect()`

Comment: Are partitions numbered/ indexed? I've never heard of it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.